# GitHub Enterprise source code - compiled or viewable?

Tags: github, open-source, enterprise, source-code-protection

GitHub has an Enterprise version which can be hosted on own servers.

They probably don’t sell the whole code when you’re on an enterprise plan, but how does GitHub protect the back-end code?

I know that the front-end code must be viewable, like the html, css and javascript.

According to some sources the public version of GitHub’s back-end is written in node.js, Ruby on Rails or Erlang. How would they compile for example the node.js part?

Companies could just go for the enterprise version and as soon as they have everything running they could stop paying GitHub, that’s why I assume that the code must be compiled or protected in some way.

Answer (score 1):

They encode the code with [Ruby Encoder](http://www.rubyencoder.com/).